# bootstrap toggle always on

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a simple question regarding bootstrap4
I am trying to follow the documentation in order to properly add a nav bar to my app.

But for some reason the toggle seem to be always on when I am on a full width browser. I even copy past the code from the doc but the toggle is still on .. 
What is going on?

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

here is the fiddle: 
https://jsfiddle.net/phknncry/1/

I get that:
[image]

when I should get:
[image]

Comment: i don't see any issue, it seems to work fine

Comment: jsfiddle works fine for me

Comment: can you see the menu ? I am getting what I see in the first picture ?

Comment: Breakpoint is...ehm...~990px (do you need lower width breakpoint?)...fiddle works fine.

Comment: the thing is no matter how large my windows is .. I never see the menu but always the toggle button

Comment: Problem is somewhere else in your code. Your example is minimal, for sure, but it is not complete and verifiable.

Comment: From question and comments it is clear there is something wrong with your testing environment. The cause is impossible to determine without being able to inspect it. So, if you do need help, you have to provide a [mcve] (live snippet) reproducing the issue in the question itself or in the fiddle you linked. Besides, please note in jsFiddle the *window* width of your example is the width of the **result panel** (right-lower panel). You can resize that panel and see it works properly. You don't need to resize the entire jsFiddle window.